# Populate react-select with image

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How do I pass options to preview images in select. I have country select and I would like to preview country flags. I don't know how to pass the  "options" object in this case.

```
    var countries = 
    [
          {value: 'me', label: 'Montenegro'},
          {value:'rs',label: 'Serbia' }
    ];

   <Select name={"nationality_" + passenger.passengerId}
           value={passenger.nationality}
           options={countries}/>
```

Answer (score 29):

Gaurav's answer works but you lose the ability to search an option by its label.

Instead, use the prop `formatOptionLabel` which allows you to change the default format:

```js
const countries = [
  { value: 'me', label: 'Montenegro', image: '…' },
  { value:'rs', label: 'Serbia', image: '…' }
];

<ReactSelect
  value={passenger.nationality}
  options={countries}
  formatOptionLabel={country => (
    <div className="country-option">
      <img src={country.image} alt="country-image" />
      <span>{country.label}</span>
    </div>
  )}
/>
```

From the doc:

> **`formatOptionLabel`**
>
> Formats option labels in the menu and control as React components

https://react-select.com/props#select-props

Comment: Oh my god, I've been struggling with this for hours, and all I needed to do was use `formatOptionLabel` instead of trying to pass JSX as the label value directly. Thank you!!

Comment: greate It' worked for me

Answer (score 27):

Change the label in countries to html.

```js
const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: <div><img src={copyIcon} height="30px" width="30px"/>Chocolate </div> },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
  ];
```

Like this add this will add image in options for select.

Comment: You can't display images like this in react? You have to write something like <img src=require(path) /> so that is the problem.

Comment: yeah, you are right. But here I was giving the example only.

Comment: Searching doesn't work tho. Type "Choco" and the select won't return "Chocolate".

Answer (score 7):

In my case, when I want to render Country flags, I just add third value to single options, look below:

```
var countries = 
[
      {value: 'me', label: 'Montenegro', flagPath: <relative-path-to-flag>},
      {value:'rs',label: 'Serbia', flagPath: <relative-path-to-flag> }
];
```

And if You want to render flag in dropdown options use 'component.Option', but it wouldn't display flag in selected option, for this you have to use 'component.SingleValue', for example:

```
singleOption = (props: OptionProps<any>) => (
<components.Option {...props}>
  {props.data.flagPath? DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR ICON HERE : null}
  {props.label}
</components.Option>)


singleValue = (props: any) => (
<components.SingleValue {...props}>
  {props.data.flagPath?DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR ICON HERE: null}
</components.SingleValue>
```

)

Then You must use components inside Select, like this:

```
<Select
      ...
      components={{ 
        Option: this.singleOption, 
        SingleValue: this.singleValue
      }}
    />
```

Hope it will help someone to resolve this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're wanting your select to behave like last but one (Custom Placeholder, Option, Value, and Arrow Components) in [this demo](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/). [Click here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/CustomComponents.js) to find out the way they've designed their ones for demo

Comment: Is there any way to use an image path for this in case gravatars are not an option?

Comment: That page 404 :(

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best solution for everybody, but it was the best for me. I was trying to figure out how to do this and [this post](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2553#issuecomment-390197214) was great a help. Props to Canda.

## Explanation/Steps

**1.** Define your options as normal, but add an extra key, called `image`. This should contain an image URL.

**2.** Modify the react-select components so that both selected and non-selected options will have images next to them.

**3.** Add some custom styles to the components to ensure the images are displayed properly.

**4.** Use the `Select` component with some awesome images!

## Final Code

```
// Step 1
const options = [
    {
        label: 'Option 1',
        value: 0,
        image: 'https://example.com/amazing-image-1.png',
    },
    {
        label: 'Option 2',
        value: 1,
        image: 'https://example.com/amazing-image-2.png',
    }
];

// Step 2
import { components } from 'react-select';
const { SingleValue, Option } = components;

const IconSingleValue = (props) => (
    <SingleValue {...props}>
        <img src={props.data.image} style={{ height: '30px', width: '30px', borderRadius: '50%', marginRight: '10px' }}/>
        {props.data.label}
    </SingleValue>
);

const IconOption = (props) => (
    <Option {...props}>
        <img src={props.data.image} style={{ height: '30px', width: '30px', borderRadius: '50%', marginRight: '10px' }}/>
        {props.data.label}
    </Option>
);

// Step 3
const customStyles = {
    option: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }),
    singleValue: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }),
}

// Step 4
import Select from 'react-select';

[...]
    <Select
        styles={customStyles}
        components={SingleValue: IconSingleValue, Option: IconOption }
        options={options}
    />
[...]
```

I'm by no means an expert with this library. I just wanted to share what I found to be a pretty simple solution to what seems to be a common problem. If something can be done better, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

formatOptionLabel - Worked for me.

```
<ReactSelect
  name={'logo_' + attributes.option_id}
  value={options.filter(obj => selectedValue.value === obj.value)}
  formatOptionLabel={option => (
                    <div>
                        {option.image ? <img src={option.image} /> : ''}
                        <span>{option.label}</span>
                    </div>
                )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note the following:

1. I am using chakra UI for my styling
2. This is a Next project
3. My images are stored as exportable SVG components e.g

```js
    export const YoutubeIcon = (props: any) => {
      return (
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 16 12" {...props}>
          <path fill="#ED1D24" d="M15.67 2.14A2 2 0 0 0 14.25.72C13 .38 8 .38 8 .38s-5 0-6.25.34A2 2 0 0 0 .33 2.14C0 3.39 0 6 0 6s0 2.61.33 3.86a2 2 0 0 0 1.42 1.42c1.25.34 6.25.34 6.25.34s5 0 6.25-.34a2 2 0 0 0 1.42-1.42C16 8.61 16 6 16 6s0-2.61-.33-3.86Z"/>
          <path fill="#fff" d="M6.36 8.37 10.55 6 6.36 3.63v4.74Z"/>
        </svg>
      )
    }
```

**STEP 1:** List with the data to be used by your select

```
export const socials = [
  {
    title: 'Youtube',
    value: 'youtube',
    icon: YoutubeIcon
  },
  {
    title: 'Discord',
    value: 'discord',
    icon: DiscordIcon
  },
  {
    title: 'Facebook',
    value: 'facebook',
    icon: FbIcon
  },
  {
    title: 'Twitter',
    value: 'twitter',
    icon: TwitterIcon
  },
];
```

**STEP 2:** Map the list of the previous step into HTML

```
const social = socials.map(socialChannels => ({
    value: socialChannels.value.toLowerCase(),
    label: (
      <Flex alignItems='center' gap='0.5rem'>
        <Box width='1rem'>{socialChannels.icon && <socialChannels.icon />}</Box>
        <Text>{socialChannels.title}</Text>
      </Flex>
    ),
  }));
```

**STEP 3:** Create your select and add the HTML object you created previously

```
<Select options={social}
   name='eventPlatform'
   id='eventPlatform'
   components={{ IndicatorSeparator: () => null }}
/>
```

Comment: This is the method worked for me as formatOptionLabel didn't

Comment: @Daniel Sanatana Thank you so much. Just started contributing on here recently so I'm still at loss on how to properly do that. I just wanted to contribute on something that gave me a tough time. Thanks for your correction again!